# Dask map_partitions return multiple output?

Tags: python, dask

**Background:**

- train.csv datasets has over 100m records
- Tried on first 1m records

I wrote two functions:

1, `func1`: apply to the partitions of the train, and return **1 new dataframe**

2, `func2`: apply to the partitions of the train, and return **2 new dataframes**

**Problems:**

1. Use map_partition(func1), a concat dataframe was returned. -- Worked

*(well, i thought it should return a dask dataframe with partitions, but i googled it out, which says dask will concat the result if it returns a dataframe. ok, no problems here)*

2. Use map_partition(func2), which returns 2 dataframes. -- Failed. I
   got 'too many values to unpack (expected 2)' error.

*(Apparently , I can run the func1 twice which return 1 dataframe each time, but it is time consuming and i think there should have ways to do both in one go...)*

Sample code below:

```
def func1(df):

   #data processing

   return new_df


def func2(df):

   #data processing

   return new_df1, new_df2


output1 = train.map_partition(func1, meta = train)  # Worked

output1, output2 = train.map_partition(func2, meta = train)  # Error:'too many values to unpack (expected 2)'
```

Let me know if more information needed.

Comment: map_partitions can't return multiple outputs. One alternative may be to convert your Dask DataFrame to [Delayed objects](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/delayed.html) and work on that.